# Javascript reverse function trouble

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I wanted to reverse a string using a recursive function. The question is why does this function return `undefined`?

```js
const reverse = function(str) {
  const looper = function(str, index) {
    if (index < 0) {
      return '';
    }
    return str[index] + looper(str, index - 1);
  };

  looper(str, str.length - 1);
};

console.log(reverse('Hello World!'));
```

Comment: Your function `looper` returns a string. But your function `reverse` returns nothing (aka `undefined`). Try using `return looper(str, str.length - 1)` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add return statement to your main function

```js
const reverse = function(str) {
    const looper = function(str, index) {
        if(index < 0) {
            return '';
        }
        return str[index] + looper(str, index - 1);
    };

    return looper(str, str.length - 1);
};

console.log(reverse('Hello World!'));
```

Comment: You should mention that the `looper` `str` parameter doesn't make sense – it's just shadowing the outer `str` and never changes

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you can do it using destructuring

```js
const reverse = ([x,...xs]) =>
  x === undefined
    ? ''
    : reverse (xs) + x

console.log (reverse ('hello world'))
// 'dlrow olleh'

console.log (reverse (''))
// ''
```

And now with a tail call

```js
const reverse = ([x,...xs], k = x => x) =>
  x === undefined
    ? k ('')
    : reverse (xs, next =>
        k (next + x))

console.log (reverse ('hello world'))
// 'dlrow olleh'

console.log (reverse (''))
// ''
```

---

Now we'll do it without destructuring

```js
const reverse = xs =>
  xs.length === 0
    ? ''
    : reverse (xs.slice (1)) + xs.slice (0,1)

console.log (reverse ('hello world'))
// 'dlrow olleh'
  
console.log (reverse (''))
// ''
```

And here it is with a tail call

```js
const reverse = (xs, k = x => x) =>
  xs.length === 0
    ? k ('')
    : reverse (xs.slice (1), next =>
        k (next + xs.slice (0,1)))

console.log (reverse ('hello world'))
// 'dlrow olleh'

console.log (reverse (''))
// ''
```

Some prefer `.substr` instead of `.slice` and `.concat` instead of `+` – it's up to you

```js
const reverse = (xs, k = x => x) =>
  xs.length === 0
    ? k ('')
    : reverse (xs.substr (1), next =>
        k (next.concat (xs.substr (0,1))))

console.log (reverse ('hello world'))
// 'dlrow olleh'

console.log (reverse (''))
// ''
```